# How to write shim for ExecuteReaderAsync?

Tags: unit-tests

I have the following method and want to write shim for the needed functionalities in it include `ExecuteReaderAsync`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ApplicationSetting>> LoadSettingsAsync(string[] keys)
{
    await using var sourceConnection = new SqlConnection(_options.Value.StoreConnectionString);
    await sourceConnection.OpenAsync();

    SqlCommand command =
        new SqlCommand(
            SqlStatements.SelectMultipleKeys(_options.Value.DefaultStoreTableName,
                _options.Value.DefaultStoreSchema), sourceConnection);
    command.AddArrayParameters(ColumnNames.Keys, keys);
    var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

    List<ApplicationSetting> settings = new();
    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        settings.Add(new ApplicationSetting(reader[ColumnNames.Key].ToString()!,
            reader[ColumnNames.Value].ToString(), reader[ColumnNames.Type].ToString()!));

    await reader.CloseAsync();
    await sourceConnection.CloseAsync();
    return settings;
}
```

Test Method:

```
[Fact]
public async Task LoadSettingsAsync_WhenCall_LoadApplicationSettings()
{
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        // Arrange
        var keys = new string[] { "key1", "key2" };

        // simulate a connection
        ShimSqlConnection.AllInstances.OpenAsyncCancellationToken = (connection, token) =>
        {
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        };
        //string commandText;

        // shim-Mock all called methods
        ShimSqlCommand.AllInstances.ExecuteReaderAsync = command =>
        {
            return Task.FromResult(???????????????????????);
        };
        var rowCounter = 0;
        ShimSqlDataReader.AllInstances.Read = (sender) =>
        {
            rowCounter++;
            return rowCounter <= 2;
        };

        ShimSqlConnection.AllInstances.Close = connection => { };

        // Act
        var ex = await Record.ExceptionAsync(() =>
            _myClass.LoadSettingsAsync(keys));

        // Assert
        ex.Should().BeNull();
    }
}
```

I tried `Substitute.For<SqlDataReader>()` to create an instance `SqlDataReader` but it throws `System.InvalidOperationException`

Then I tried this code:

```
ShimSqlCommand.AllInstances.ExecuteReaderAsync = async command =>
{
     return new ShimSqlDataReader();
};
```

But it throw `NullReferenceException` on `await reader.ReadAsync()` line (note: reader has value):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

```csharp
ShimSqlCommand.AllInstances.ExecuteReaderAsync = command => Task.FromResult((SqlDataReader)new ShimSqlDataReader());
```

The `ExecuteReaderAsync` wants a `Task<SqlDataReader>` as a return type.
`Task.FromResult()` is for the `Task` part.
`ShimSqlDataReader` is a derived class from `ShimBase<SqlDataReader>` and you can cast it to `SqlDataReader` without any problem. The class is included in the Fakes you don't need to create it yourself.

NB:
`ShimSqlDataReader` can directly be used like this:

```csharp
ShimSqlCommand.AllInstances.ExecuteReader = command => new ShimSqlDataReader();
```

for an `ExecuteReader` shim (without the `async`).